# NGINX images not displaying

Tags: php, html, css, nginx

Can anybody tell me why NGINX does not display my images in my "img" folder? It's irritating the life out of me. Apache works "out of the box". Everywhere I look I cant find a simple answer. Could someone please explain a simple solution. My CSS files are working, they are in the root folder with index.php, but clearly, NGINX is not looking anywhere other than the server root folder

Comment: there must be something misconfigured but without the config shown, we won't be able to help...

Comment: Why should nginx look "anywhere other than the server root folder"? Have you configured the server to do so? What does that mean for the folder with images?

Comment: What is your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` setting? There should be a line `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` and it need to be uncommented out in order for nginx to recognise the mine types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Nginx settings,

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;
    root /var/www/travellist/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't have two web servers installed on the same machine(NGINX & Appach), it's like havine two software firewalls and they won't work properly.
If NGINX is well configured, desactivate Appach.

Comment: Because they are both two web servers and it will make a conflict in machine. you can only have one web server in a machine

Comment: if you want to keep both of them, make them listen to different port because the defaul web port is 80

Comment: And how is this related to the question? Why do you think that both servers are running and the user was not able to configure them properly?